# Getting this error "cannot access scala.reflect.api.TypeTags"

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am migrating from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.1. During the maven build, I encountered this error in one of the Java class at the below mentioned method.

> "**cannot access scala.reflect.api.TypeTags - class file for scala.reflect.api.TypeTags not found**"

This is my code

```
private Dataset<Row> getEmptyDataFrame(String columnName) {
    StructType structType = new StructType().add(columnName, DataTypes.StringType);
    return spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), structType);
  }
```

Where 'spark' and 'sc' are SparkSession and JavaSparkContext object respectively.

I am using scala-reflect 2.11.8 jar

Need to know root cause of this error.

Comment: Code you wrote is irrelevant to the error. You can check that [new project](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/4c50654537040a8216a38a40bccc358c) with spark dependency and your code compiles without errors. Check `pom.xml`. Also you can try `mvn clean compile`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The scope for scala-reflect jar was given 'runtime'. So, it couldn't fetch it during maven build/compilation.